# Executable jar cannot find resources

Tags: java, maven

Here's my maven structure:

```
project
  ---src
    ----main
        ----java
            ----App.java
        ----resources
            ----config.properties
```

Here is the code to read config.properties:

```
private static final URL propFile = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("config.properties");

public App() throws IOException {
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile.getFile()));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        App app = new App();
        //Something interesting happens here
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run `java -jar MyApp-1.0.jar`, I receive the `FileNotFoundException`:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/home/dragon/JavaProjects/MyApp/target/MyApp-1.0.jar!/config.properties (No such file or directory)

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of these should work just fine:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));
// OR
props.load(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("config.properties");
```

In your example, you are trying to access files that are embedded in a JAR archive, via a `FileInputStream`, which you cannot do directly.

Comment: Yes, this works great.
But I cannot understand why Java doesn't look to classes folder in my base variant.

Comment: @Dragon - see edit. Your app is JAR'ed, so you won't be able to use a file output stream to retrieve embedded resources. You could have just asked instead of downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

In your java folder you should place App.java and resources catalog. Then you could get properties file using this code:

```
private static final URL propFile = getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/config.properties");

public App() throws IOException {
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile.getFile()));
}
```

So your project structure would look like:

```
project
  ---src
    ----main
        ----java
            ----App.java
            ----resources
                ----config.properties
```

Comment: getClass cannot be referenced from a static context. And `NullPointerException` is received then.

Comment: Could you post full code please? (also to avoid NullPointerException you should check before loading props if it isn't null - if (propFile != null) then load it).

Comment: According to standard maven directory layout I have correct project structure. (Edited topic giving more code).